# Selecting the correct language in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, testing, localization

I'm currently adding localisation to an iOS (iPhone only) App and have come across some problems.

**The "language names" are in the native language making it hard to select the correct language. Is there a list of translations of the iPhone list:**

[image: language names #1]
[image: language names #2]

**Are the languages guaranteed to be in the same order?** Can an index value be used to reference a language?

*NB: Is this the best place to post this question, I realise it blurs the foundry between usability, testing and programming.*

Answer (score 2):

I found this [blog post](http://kb.applingua.com/2011/07/which-languages-does-ios-support/) that is very useful:

[image: iOS Languages, translated]

List of supported languages (as of iOS 4.x):

English (U.S.), English (UK), French (France), German, Traditional Chinese, Simplified Chinese, Dutch, Italian, Spanish, Portuguese (Brazil), Portuguese (Portugal), Danish, Swedish, Finnish, Norwegian, Korean, Japanese, Russian, Polish, Turkish, Ukrainian, Hungarian, Arabic, Thai, Czech, Greek, Hebrew, Indonesian, Malay, Romanian, Slovak, Croatian, Catalan, and Vietnamese

Answer (score 1):

In my experience they are not guaranteed to be in the same order. You must look at all the strings and do your best.